# Training custom image from Tesseract 5

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to train the tesseract model from a custom image using Tesseract 5 on ubuntu 18.04 but I am getting errors while performing training but i am getting below error

> tesseract "data/IND-ground-truth/19.tif" data/IND-ground-truth/19 --psm 6 lstm.train
> Error in pixReadMemTiff: function not present
> Error in pixReadMem: tiff: no pix returned
> Error in pixaGenerateFontFromString: pix not made
> Error in bmfCreate: font pixa not made
> Error in findTiffCompression: function not present
> Error in pixReadFromMultipageTiff: function not present
> tesseract "data/IND-ground-truth/11.tif" data/IND-ground-truth/11 --psm 6 lstm.train

I am following Tesseract official GitHub : https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesstrain

Just help in resolving this above error.

.

Answer (score 0):

You compiled leptonica (tesseract dependancy) without tiff support

Comment: i have installed  sudo apt install libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libwebp-dev libopenjp2-7-dev libgif-dev and then ./configure --with-libtiff this is the right way to compiled with tiff support

Comment: `--with-libtiff` argument for `configure` is useless as it is enabled by default (e.g. when libtiff5-dev is present it is used).

Comment: but still i am facing the same issue

Comment: what is the output of the command `tesseract --version`?